# JavaScript get function value

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to override Node.js require function. 
However in JavaScript functions can have values and properties

Assuming code like this

```
a = function() {};
a.someParam1 = 1;
a.someParam2 = 2;
```

If I console log it. It'd look like:

```
{ [Function] someParam1: 1, someParam2: 2 }
```

I know I can call this function by simply doing

```
a()
```

But what If I wanted to override it's behavior without getting rid of properties?

Doing

```
a = function(){ console.log("Some other function")}
console.log(a.someParam1)
```

would yield undefined.

How can I override function value without touching it's parameters?

Comment: Overriding `require()` is not a good idea.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: a bracket is missing from `console.log("Some other function"`... but i guess that was just a typo... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = (function(previously) {
  var newImplementation = function() {
    // new implementation
  }
  for (var x in previously) {
     newImplementation[x] = previously[x];
  }
  return newImplementation;
})(a);
```

Comment: This is a little bit way around. Aren't there any properties that can give me just the value?

Comment: No. JavaScript functions are objects. When you replace the value of an object, you are not "overriding" anything; you are replacing an object reference with another object reference. So if you want the second reference to have the first reference's properties, you have to copy them.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit, but that's **not recommended***. (But since what you want to do isn't recommended in the first place you might as well give it a shot.)

```
a = function() {return "something"};
a.someParam1 = 1;
a.someParam2 = 2;
a = Object.setPrototypeOf(function(){return "something else";},a);
```

> ***Warning:** Mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object, using either this
>   method or the deprecated Object.prototype.__proto__, is strongly
>   discouraged, because it is very slow and unavoidably slows down subsequent execution in modern JavaScript implementations.
>   [source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 1):

The function object **is** the function. The function is not some kind of property of an abstract object whose "value" (the function) can be overridden. You cannot override the value of a function any more than you can override the number 1 with the number 2.

You can attach properties to the function, being an object, but the function is the function and cannot be changed out from underneath itself.

I don't know in what environment a `console.log` would print out `{ [Function] someParam1: 1, someParam2: 2 }`. It certainly does not in any environment I'm familiar with. `console.log` on a function, with or without associated properties, would print out the function.

```
> a = function() {};
> a.someParam1 = 1;
> a.someParam2 = 2;

> console.log(a)
function () {}
```

If you want to move the properties onto a different function, feel free with `Object.assign(function newFunc() { }, oldFunc)` or `_.extend` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: nice, didn't know about Object.assign. It's currently FF only, but good to know it's coming :)

Comment: Also available in traceur.